# UIRefreshControl not centred with contentInset set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a refresh control added to a collection view.  Everything working, but when I set the collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 20, 20) the width of the refresh control stays the same but is shifted 20px, so is not centred in the view.  The control should be reduced by 40px for it to be correct.

```
self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:rect collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 20, 20)
UIRefreshControl* pullDownRefresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[pullDownRefresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.collectionView addSubview:pullDownRefresh];
```

I have tried setting the width manually after adding the view (also in viewWillLayoutSubviews), and playing with autoresizingMask to no avail.

Any ideas?  I guess I will need to resort to putting it in a container view...but shouldn't need to!

Comment: container view doesn't work as UIRefreshControl asserts if not added to a scroll view!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, fixed the problem by not setting collectionView.contentInset.  Instead I set on the flowLayout

i.e.

```
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 20, 20);
```

Comment: Saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't fit my needs, because I had a complicated collectionView with multiple types of cells and each had specific insets for sections, so I didn't want to dive in and add complexity with this solution.

What worked for me was pretty easy. Add the `UIRefreshControl` to the `collectionView`'s backgroundView instead:

```
collectionView.backgroundView = viewModel.refreshControl
```

And when finishing the refresh, just do this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.viewModel.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}
```